# Span Overlay Element Bad Position

Tags: html, css

On my website (http://milesopedia.com) I have this overlay on the image but the icon is not correctly aligned, as you can see here:

[image: current problem]

It's a Wordpress-based blog with a theme and if I look at the preview of the theme (http://themes.tielabs.com/sahifa/category/world/) the element is correctly positioned:

[image]

I have compared the html and css and they seem identical to me. The markup uses a span with a pseudo before element to render the icon. I can't find the source of the problem.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="post-thumbnail">
    <a href="http://milesopedia.com/conseils/ou-partir/partir-a-nouvelle-orleans-points-miles" rel="bookmark">
        <img width="310" height="165" src="http://i1.wp.com/milesopedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Canal_Streetcar_in_New_Orleans_Louisiana_USA.jpg?resize=310%2C165" class="attachment-tie-medium size-tie-medium wp-post-image" alt="Photo: Didier Moïse">                                
        <span class="fa overlay-icon"></span> 
    </a> 
</div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like a positioning issue to me though.

Comment: Just noticed, that your `img` element is not properly closed (should be like this: `<img src="..." />`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `display: inline;` for that `<span>` element.

Answer (score 2):

Override this rule inherited from `font-awesome.css`:

```
.fa {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
}
```

I've just tried to disable it in inspector and icon got centered as you expect.

**UPD:**
Or, as per @jacob answer, there is a cleaner approach just setting `display: inline` for your icon `span` element.